# How to create a new vim filetype?

Tags: filetype

I have html settings set up in my `~/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim` file.  I would like these settings to apply to Rhtml files as well.  I made a symbolic link with

```
ln -s ~/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim ~/.vim/ftplugin/Rhtml.vim
```

Why doesn't this load my html settings when I open a .Rhtml file?

Comment: I don't know why a symlink doesn't work, but the usual approach for this is to create a `rhtml.vim` file which uses `runtime! ftplugin/html.vim`. [Here's an example](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/ftplugin/gohtmltmpl.vim).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I like the `runtime! ftplugin/html.vim` idea, but I can't get that to work either.  I copied your example to ftplugin/rhtml.vim but it doesn't work.  When I open a .Rhtml file, the default vim settings apply.  When I try `set ft=html`, the html settings load.  What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the `filetype` is set correct? What does `verbose set filetype?` say?

Comment: You mean enter `:verbose set filetype` as a command from within vim? I get `filetype=`.  This means there is no filetype set for my .Rhtml file, right?

Comment: Yeah, I meant as a command. How are you setting the filetype? Is it possible you forgot to add a `ftdetect` script? (like [this one](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/ftdetect/gofiletype.vim)?)

Comment: It seems you are right that the missing `ftdetect` is the issue.  Where should I create the file?

Comment: See `:help new-filetype`

Comment: Ah, the `:help new-filetype` page explained it.  @Rich, @Carpetsmoker, thanks for you help.  If anyone else is confused about this, vim needs to be configured to detect new filetype extensions beyond some defaults. The instructions are in `:help new-filetype`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The symlink you've created at `~/.vim/ftplugin/Rhtml.vim` tells Vim how to handle files with the `RHTML` filetype, but you haven't told Vim how to *recognise* which files should have this filetype.

Instructions for how to do so can be found in the documentation by running the command [`:help new-filetype`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#new-filetype).

You can use either the technique described in section A or the one from section C for your purposes. (The former is arguably simpler, but has a couple of disadvantages compared to the latter, which are described in the docs.)

Answer (score 22):

Create `~/.vim/ftdetect/SOME_EXTENSION.vim` and add this line to it:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.SOME_EXTENSION set filetype=SOME_FILETYPE
```

So if you wanted vim to use the filetype `html` for all files with an `.Rhtml` extension you would add this to `~/.vim/ftdetect/rhtml.vim`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.Rhtml set filetype=html
```

Comment: I'm glad to see an answer that spells out how to actually accomplish what the OP wanted! Welcome to [vi.se]!