# Let .js files be recognized as .jsx files?

Tags: vimscript, filetype, filetype-javascript

I just figured out how to combine those creepy plugins to work together to achieve the following auto-indent:

**before** / **after** pressing `o`:

[image]
[image]

But then this only works on file extension `.jsx` as shown above, while most of the legacy files I'm working on have file extension `.js` but all using `.jsx` syntax, and in those files the above behaviour won't work:

**before** / **after** pressing `o`:

[image]
[image]

As you can see the indentation is incorrect. So as my title, how can I make (neo)Vim consider all `.js` as `.jsx` by default?

Comment: source the jsx indent scripts in your `js` filetype configuration

Comment: See [`:help new-filetype`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#new-filetype). Either of the techniques in section A or C will work.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/). I'm inclined to agree that this is a duplicate of https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13623/how-to-create-a-new-vim-filetype; does it answer your question?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: I'm not sure about it, since all of these settings about indentation are from some plugins I downloaded. I imported these plugins in my .vimrc file, and some of them work without additional settings while others require some variables like `let g:closetag_filenames = '*.js,*.jsx,*.html,*.xhtml,*.phtml'` to be set/customized. But what I want to achieve is let `.js` be seen as `.jsx` from the perspective of plugin-in makers.

Comment: @job_start Switching the filetype should be enough to do that; alternatively, as Christian points out, you can make your js filetype `:runtime[!]` scripts for `jsx`. If this is plugin specific, please [edit] the question with all the relevant details.

Comment: It seems jsx extension triggers filetype `javascriptreact`, while js triggers `javascript` (you can confirm that with `:set ft?`). But it seems the indent behavior for `javascriptreact` (from Vim built-in runtime) is to just mimic `javascript`: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/indent/javascriptreact.vim, so not sure where the behavior you're seeing is coming from... Do you have additional plug-ins for `javascript` or `javascriptreact`? You could post output of `:scriptnames` to show what gets loaded for you...

Comment: Also consider that there's good reason for indentation to work differently in those two cases. The syntax of `return` with a HTML/XML object is not really valid JavaScript, only valid for React (AFAIK), so there's good reason to use a different file extension (jsx) for that. What's the reason why you'd want to use that syntax in a js file? Can't you rename it to jsx since that's what it seems to be?