# Syntax highlight for .tpl / cloud-config / cloud-init files

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I am using [`cloud-init`](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to parametrize cloud clusters. This is achieved via `#cloud-config` files, which usually have a `.tpl` or `.tf.tpl` extension. Here are [a few examples](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/examples.html), one of them illustrated below:

```yaml
#cloud-config
# vim: syntax=yaml
#
# This is the configuration syntax that the write_files module
# will know how to understand. Encoding can be given b64 or gzip or (gz+b64).
# The content will be decoded accordingly and then written to the path that is
# provided. 
#
# Note: Content strings here are truncated for example purposes.
write_files:
- encoding: b64
  content: CiMgVGhpcyBmaWxlIGNvbnRyb2xzIHRoZSBzdGF0ZSBvZiBTRUxpbnV4...
  owner: root:root
  path: /etc/sysconfig/selinux
  permissions: '0644'
- content: |
    # My new /etc/sysconfig/samba file

    SMBDOPTIONS="-D"
  path: /etc/sysconfig/samba
- content: !!binary |
    f0VMRgIBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAIAPgABAAAAwARAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAJAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAOAAI
    AEAAHgAdAAYAAAAFAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAEAAAAAAAEAAQAAAAAAAwAEAAAAAAADAAQAAAAAAAAgA
    AAAAAAAAAwAAAAQAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAACQAAAAAAAAAJAAAAAAAAcAAAAAAAAABwAAAAAAAAAAQAA
    ....
  path: /bin/arch
  permissions: '0555'
- encoding: gzip
  content: !!binary |
    H4sIAIDb/U8C/1NW1E/KzNMvzuBKTc7IV8hIzcnJVyjPL8pJ4QIA6N+MVxsAAAA=
  path: /usr/bin/hello
  permissions: '0755'
```

This format represents `yaml` in a way. I haven't found any plugin specifically for such files. Are there any plugins or should I configure `vim` to use a similar syntax highlighting for such files?

In case I should use another syntax, which one would you recommend? And how should I configure `vim` to use another syntax as an alias?

Comment: Plugin requests are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

To use `filetype=yaml` for `*.tpl` (which includes `*.tf.tpl`) files, you would create the following file
`~/.vim/ftdetect/tpl.vim` with this content:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.tpl set filetype=yaml
```

This way, cloud-config files will become aliases of YAML files.

Also see the answers to [How to create a new vim filetype?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13623/how-to-create-a-new-vim-filetype) Read `:help new-filetype` for documentation on how to add new filetypes to Vim and what can be done beyond defining aliases. Feel free to refine your question or ask a new one for concrete problems in the process.

The detected filetype can be overridden using a modeline as you seem to have tried. Note the differences between the `syntax` and `filetype` options (see `:help 'syntax'` and `:help 'filetype'`).
The modeline to treat a file as YAML would be:

```
# vim: set filetype=yaml
```

As for the recommendations on plugins and filetypes, that's really up to you. You're working with those cloud-config files and you should use whatever makes you productive. Nobody else will be able to give you an answer of what works best for you.